# Помогите достать из строки число (Lua)

Tags: lua

Имеется строка

```
local test = "§a402,097,152§r"
```

Нужно достать число из строки.
Только есть проблема что количество чисел может изменятся с 1 до 9.
То есть число там может быть 704,512 или 352 или 0.

Зарание спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/dOGdSY

```
local s = "§a402,097,152§r"
local x = s:match("[%d,]+"):gsub(",", "")
print(x)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Answer (score 1):

```
local test = "§a402,097,152§r"

-- Поиск первого числа
local result = string.match(test, "%d+")
print(result)

-- Поиск всех чисел
local results = string.gmatch(test, "%d+")
for w in results  do
    print(w)
end
```